# Revert database in Entity Framework code-first

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first

I made a in my model and updated database using

```
Add-Migration sdfgfsd
Update-Database
```

Now I  found the change I just made is not necessary.

I would like do revert both code and database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Yes - it's straightforward. Use

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:zzzz
```

Where `zzzz` is the name of the migration before the one you want to rollback.

**EDIT**
You then need to delete the migration(s) after zzzz.

If you want to rollback all migrations, or if you only have one migration, use

```
update-database -target:0
```

Comment: why should  delete zzzz?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you delete the one you don't want.

Comment: @KuttanSujith The 'zzzz' migration in Peter's example is the migration you want to rollback. So you go back to a point prior to it, and then delete it from your code.