# Rename a column and also changing the column type through migration in EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am new to Asp. Net MVC 5 architecture and also don't know much about Entity Framework Code First Migrations. Here's my snap to the table i created through migration, due to some reasons i just want to rename the ReleaseDate Column to ReleasedDate and also want to change the column type of Genre id from byte to int. Is there anyway to do so through migrations or any other alternatives?

[Snap ot the Migration Of My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW8fG.png)

Code for the Migration:

```
 namespace Vidly.Migrations
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

        public partial class AddPropAndAnnotationsToMovie : DbMigration
        {
            public override void Up()
            {

                CreateTable(
                "dbo.Movies",
                c => new
                                    {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                    GenreId = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                    DateAdded = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ReleaseDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    NumberInStock = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                    .ForeignKey("dbo.Genres", t => t.GenreId, cascadeDelete: true)
                    .Index(t => t.GenreId);

                CreateTable(
                "dbo.Genres",
                c => new
                                    {
                    Id = c.Byte(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
            }

            public override void Down()
            {
                DropForeignKey("dbo.Movies", "GenreId", "dbo.Genres");
                DropIndex("dbo.Movies", new[] { "GenreId" });
                DropTable("dbo.Genres");
                DropTable("dbo.Movies");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post your code, not just an image. Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Sorry sir, i have attached the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either reverse the migration, edit the C# entities and create a new migration. Use:

```
`Update-database -TargetMigration:0`
```

to revert all migrations, or,

```
`Update-database -TargetMigration:"name of migration file"`
```

to revert to a specific migration. **Delete** the unwanted migration  file.

Then run `Add-migration migration-name` having changed you code to create the new migration file.

The third option is to rename the fields in code then use `Add-migration'.

Avoid editing the migration file. Change the code, run a migration, update the database.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506137/revert-database-in-entity-framework-code-first/30506470#30506470)

Comment: I have already tried this , but as i have messed up with my migrations the only option remaining is to rename the column and the column type.

Comment: Thankyou sir, it helped.

Comment: Accepted But sir i am getting  an another error in changing of attribute since the entity is an foreign key too and i can't post a new question before 90 mins,unfortunately have to wait.

Comment: Okay, best to post this as a new question. Add a comment when the next question is posted. Be sure to post the error message and the code that is generating the error.

Comment: Sir i have posted the question and tried my best to elaborate it. Help me with your knowledge. Here's the link to the question,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095923/entity-framework-migration-error-in-changing-column-type